# split the each contour seperately

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to split image based on the number of contours formed. The below image i get 2 rectangular boxes, how to split this seperately. Please help.

[image: sample_Contours.jpg]

Current Output:

[image: Cuurent Output]

Expected output:

[image: Output1]

[image: Output2]

Current output Code:

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread('C:/sample_Contours.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] 
horizontal_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,1))
detect_horizontal = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, horizontal_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_horizontal, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), thickness=15) 
vertical_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1,15))
detect_vertical = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, vertical_kernel, iterations=2)
cnts = cv2.findContours(detect_vertical, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (255,255,255), thickness=15)
cv2.imshow('thresh',thresh)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to crop 2 sub images from the original image?

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle yes based on number of rectangular boxes

Answer (score 1):

You can use cv function `boundingRect` to find the rectangle that contains the countour. Then from this rectangle it is a simple cropping.

Try something like:

```
m = 32 #crop margin
for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    crop = thresh[y-m:y+m+h,x-m:x+w+m]
```

Comment: since i am beginner into opencv could u  please tell me how to get those images sepeately also

Comment: for each iteration crop is a new image that contains only the original part of thresh that countains the countour. You can do the cropping on the original image (not thresholded) or on the original image on which you draw the contour, or....

Comment: you mean like this ```import cv2
image = cv2.imread('E:/python_anc_files/Tests/sample_Contours.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1] # automatic threshold selection using otsu

for c in cnts:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    crop = thresh[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    cv2.imshow('crop',crop)
    cv2.waitKey(0)```

Comment: i tried this but its not showing the required output

Comment: This will crop strictly the bounding rect. If you want to have some margin you can do something like `thresh[y-m:y+m+h,x-m:x+w+m]` where `m` is the margin.

Comment: could u please update accordingly to crop the rectangles seperately!